# Is there a term for something like a "routing scheme"?

Tags: schematics, communication, routing

I would like to know if there is any common term to describe the routing of devices to conceptually understand the setup. E.g. something that explains how the devices are connected to each other on a "macro scale" like this:

[image: example]

And not a concise routing between the single components like this:

[image: example 2]

Hope you get the idea of what I mean. The upper one is more for people who aren't really involved so they get a rough understand on what is going on while the lower one targets people who need precise information to realize it.

Comment: No, the picture is self explanatory - use it.

Comment: Do you mean a block diagram?

Comment: Block diagram, perfect. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for with PCB's is called "block diagrams" basically wrapping up simple functions into a block with the inputs and outputs and showing how they connect to the rest of the functional blocks. e.g. 1 block might be the micro controller and your schematic might group things up to reflect this. e.g. in Kicad hierarchical sheets can be used to make schematics that look exactly like block diagrams.

Attached below is one such block diagram from one of the projects I have worked on in the past, there are nicer ways of doing this, for me it was just to break up different areas so multiple sheets could be worked by different people at the same time.
[image]